# set text of ListView in center - android

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to set text of ListView in **center** of layout. I use LinearLayout and set *gravity = center*, but it always shows in **left**

Here is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_function" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my code, I use:

```
String[] functions = { "Login", "Register", "Setting", "About", "Exit" };
lvMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_function);
ArrayAdapter<String> arr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, functions);
// set adapter for ListView.
lvMenu.setAdapter(arr);
```

Here is result:
[result](http://i596.photobucket.com/albums/tt44/shinkt/Capture.jpg)

Do you have any idea? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: If this was the answer, could you please mark it? Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to create your own layout for your listview item. Soemthing like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your code, your going to have to do this

```
 new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.yourRowItemLayoutHere, R.id.textItem, functions);
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

- **layout_gravity** = Impact with *layout* in your child views
- **gravity** - Impact with *content* in your child views