# Android - RelativeLayout w/TextView .. text in tTextView not centering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

I been round and round on this, and I can not seem to get the text in the ListView to center. 
The ListView itself centers good, but text inside is not.. I hate to ask seems so basic..

Here is Code I have:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvVoiceReturn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mute"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mute"
        android:gravity="center" >

    </ListView>
```

Im sure its an easy line of code but i have not located it, urgh.. =/

Thank you.
Droidster

Comment: This is a ListView not TextView.

Comment: Do you mean text in a TextView? Becasue in your code is a ListView

Comment: yes, correction made above. Many thanks, andy idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used `android:gravity="center"`

This doesn't center the textview, but centers the text inside of the text view.

What you want to use is

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

If you were using a linear layout, then you could use

`android:layout_gravity="center"`

This is where you got confused, in a relative layout you can't use this because it will give you a syntax error.

Comment: I tried this but did not move the text in ListView to center of box.. =?

Comment: Look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295538/set-text-of-listview-in-center-android - or here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483788/center-text-in-a-listview

Comment: Check those links provided by jcw. There is an answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom adapter with a custom element layout file then please post the xml here. **setting gravity attribute to center for list view does not ensure that your list items are gonna center align.**